# Encode problems in python

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I am writing a telegram bot [script](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B56UMsfLF9DQLXVXY1JkSGV4cmM/view?usp=sharing) which shows the weather using this API call:

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=CITY_NAME_IN_RUSSIAN&APPID=API_KEY_HERE&lang=ru&units=metric&encode=utf-8
```

Where the parameter `CITY_NAME_IN_RUSSIAN=<city name>`.

Example city name `Moscow` is `Москва` in Russian.

If I send in English, `Moscow`, then all is normal. But if I send in Russian, `Москва`, I get an error.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 24-28: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using python 2. if so 
try `unicode('Москва','utf-8')`.

you can also add this on top of your file `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: Thanks for answer. 
I use last version of python. `CITY_NAME_IN_RUSSIAN` thats what user write and send to bot, it can be `Москва (Moscow)`, `Владивосток ( Vladivostok)` or any city. I dont know what user can send and therefore i can't use `unicode('Москва','utf-8')`. I try `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` but it dont help too.

Comment: I think first you have to parse URL (or your Russian word) with urllib.parse.quote() which replace special characters in the string using the %xx escape.

Comment: `import urllib`
`urllib.parse.quote("Москва")`
result:`'%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0'`






If you pass the resulting string in the URL then you will get the appropriate response.